# По адресу site.com/en/ должна быть версия с константами английского перевода

Tags: php

Добрый день.
К примеру есть сайт site.com, но со временем понадобилась англ версия.
По адресу site.com/en/ должна быть версия с константами английского перевода.
Как правильно организовать мультиязычность не копируя сам движок сайта в дирректорию /en/? 
Движок самописный PHP.
Поделитесь плз ссылками на подходящие ресурсы.

Answer (score 3):

А чем вас не устраивает простой вариант вида `?lang=en` помимо очевидной неэстетичности? По сути вам надо делать менять url средствами сервера приложений (гуглите mod_rewrite для Apache), но в конечном итоге вы всё равно придёте  к аргументу "под капотом". [Вот пример на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875284/language-parameter-rewrite-with-mod-rewrite), думаю перевод не требуется.

Возможны конечно и "странные", но рабочие варианты, вроде как действительно положить index.php в каждую реальную папку языка, вида:

```
// en/index.php
$global_locale = 'en';
include_once('../index.php');
```

и т.п. для каждого языка. С ходу правда не могу сообразить какие подводные камни тут могут таится, наверное будут проблемы с относительными путями в движке, но если он самописный то всё решаемо.